# From an array of objects, make an object that holds all values of identical keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I've seen this problem explained when only needing the values of one key, but not how to do it when wanting the values of multiple keys.
The object has the following structure:

`objArray = [ { foo: 1, bar: 2}, { foo: 3, bar: 4}, { foo: 5, bar: 6} ];`

I want my output to look like this:

```
newObj = [ 
           { foo: [1, 3, 5] },
           { bar: [2, 4, 6] },
];
```

Or even

```
newObj = [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]];
```

I've tried something like this:

```
  const newObj = objArray.map(({ foo, bar }) => ( foo, bar ));
```

Answer (score 1):

###Logic

- Since you need to listen to keys in an object, which in turn is a part of an array, you need multiple loops.

  - Parent Loop: On array to get individual object
  - Child Loop: Loop on keys of current object
- Using this, you can create a hashmap. If you use array here, you will have to search based on keys to push new value. hashmap reduces this effort.
- At the end, you have a single object with key and values as an array. You can loop over keys and formulate your output

```js
const objArray = [ { foo: 1, bar: 2}, { foo: 3, bar: 4}, { foo: 5, bar: 6} ];

const result = objArray.reduce((acc, item) => {
  Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    acc[key] = acc[key] || [];
    acc[key].push(value)
  })
  return acc
}, {})

const finalValue = Object.entries(result).map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }))

console.log(finalValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let objArray = [{
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2
}, {
  foo: 3,
  bar: 4
}, {
  foo: 5,
  bar: 6
}];
// 1. Get the keys
const keys = Object.keys(objArray[0]);
// Use the keys to read values from each object
const output = objArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  keys.forEach(key => {
    // if the key exists update, else initialize it
    acc[key] = acc[key] ? acc[key].concat(curr[key]) : [curr[key]]
  })
  return acc
},{})

// Your outputs ow you want them.
console.log(output)
console.log(Object.values(output))
```